# Is Samsung 970 EVO SSD compatible with Gigabyte GA-250M-DS3H

Tags: ssd, motherboard, compatibility, samsung-ssd

The [Samsung 970 EVO SSD](https://www.amazon.ca/Samsung-970-EVO-500GB-MZ-V7E500BW/dp/B07BN4NJ2J) is currently on sale for Cyber Monday and I'm looking to purchase it. I just want to confirm that it will be compatible with my motherboard. I have a [Gigabyte GA-250M-DS3H](https://www.gigabyte.com/ca/Motherboard/GA-B250M-DS3H-rev-10#kf). Looking at the specs I believe they should be compatible, but just wanted to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: If the specifications for the motherboard supports NVMe M.2 drives then it’s compatible with the drive.  Gigabyte specifications are detailed.  Do the specifications of the motherboard answer your question?

Comment: It says "1 x M.2 connector (Socket 3, M key, type 2242/2260/2280 SATA and PCIe x4/x2 SSD support)". I don't see any mention of NVMe though @Ramhound. Does this mean it won't be compatible?

Comment: M.2 PCIe is NVMe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Samsung 970 EVO SSD is currently on sale for Cyber Monday and I'm looking to purchase it. I just want to confirm that it will be compatible with my motherboard. I have a Gigabyte GA-250M-DS3H.

Your motherboard supports M.2 PCIe devices.  M.2 PCIe devices are NVMe devices.  The motherboard [manual](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-b250m-ds3h_e.pdf) specifically indicates supports for NVMe devices.